# Google Analytics pagePath issue GA4

Tags: google-analytics

I am using Google Analytics GA4 API for accessing information for my website. I am using `google.analytics.data_v1beta.types RunReportRequest` to request dimension and metric values from GA. When I make request for the dimension "pagePath" I do not get all results. I know this because if I log into my GA account I can see the expected results. For example we have a path that starts with "/library/" and there are many sub-paths from that, e.g. "/library/apps/some_app".

Using the GA API I only see "/Library/" and none of the sub-paths. I have also tried using "fullUrl" and every other related url path dimension.

Here is an example of the request.

```
request = RunReportRequest(
    property=f"properties/{property_id}",
    dimensions=[ Dimension(name="pagePath"),
                ],
    metrics=[Metric(name="screenPageViews")
                , Metric(name="activeUsers")
                # , Metric(name="newUsers")
                , Metric(name="screenPageViewsPerUser")
            ],
    date_ranges=[DateRange(start_date="2023-11-06", end_date="today")],
)
```

Yet, on GA account UI I can see all the sub-path info. What am I doing wrong?